# how to draw mixed rectangles and circles shapes on the mouseover using html5 or jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, drawing, mouseover

I'm trying to make kind of an Paint editor in my Web Application. For this, I was studying wPaint (https://github.com/websanova/wPaint), which is an jQuery plugin. With this, I can draw shapes on the mouseover, creating rectangles, lines and circles.

Although this is a great plugin, I can't draw mixed rectangles and circles shapes like this:

[image]

Is there any jQuery plugin or HTML5 Canvas library that can draw images, on the mouseover, like this?

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a project whereby you can draw the shape you have given (and any other shape) using the mouse. You can then export the results as Javascript Code using HTML5 and Canvas.

My project is at  http://canvimation.github.com/

The source code for my project is at https://github.com/canvimation/canvimation.github.com

Use the grid to obtain the right angles you need.

[image: Building the shape]    [image: Built]

Building the shape   and the       Finished shape

Exported Code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         #canvasarea
         {
            border:black 1px solid;
         }
      </style>
      <!--[IF LT IE 9]><script type="text/javascript" src = "excanvas.js" ></script><![endif]-->
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function setcanvas()
         {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasarea");
            if (canvas.getContext)
            {
               var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
               drawcanvas(ctx);
            }
            else
            {
               alert("Canvas NOT supported");
            }
         }

         function drawcanvas(ctx)
         {

               //Shape0;
               ctx.shadowColor ="rgba(0,0,0,0)";
               ctx.strokeStyle ="rgba(0,0,0,1)";
               ctx.lineWidth = 1;
               ctx.lineCap = "butt";
               ctx.lineJoin = "miter";
               ctx.beginPath();
               ctx.moveTo(177,118);
               ctx.bezierCurveTo(237,176,296,177,357,118);
               ctx.bezierCurveTo(357,148,357,208,357,238);
               ctx.bezierCurveTo(312,238,222,238,177,238);
               ctx.bezierCurveTo(177,208,177,148,177,118);
               ctx.closePath();
               ctx.stroke();
               ctx.shadowOffsetX = 15;
               ctx.shadowOffsetY = 15;
               ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
               ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
               ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0)";
               ctx.fill();
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="setcanvas()">
      <canvas id="canvasarea" width="1000" height="500"></canvas>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, nice tool! But what I'm looking for is for something that can be added to my web application. I'd like to create shapes on my own app, know what I mean? I understood that in this case, I would use an third party tool (yours) to create the shape and then import it to my web appplication

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any HTML5 Canvas library that can draw images, on the
>   mouseover, like this?

Try any one of these two:

http://processingjs.org/

http://paperjs.org/